# Accessing Sass List Element with index

Tags: sass

I am trying to put a resolution range per size of the device

```
$screen:       "only screen" !default
$medium-range:  (40.063em, 64em)
```

Now, I wanted to get the element of it, so I created a function for it

```
@function upper-bound($list)
    @return list.nth($list, 2)

@function lower-bound($list)
    @return list.nth($list, 1)
```

I am trying to `interpolate` the `function` that I have created

```
$medium-only:  "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})" !default
```

But when I look at the generated `CSS`, it becomes like this.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:$lower-bound($medium-range)) and (max-width:upper-bound(40.063em, 64em)) {}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realised that it isn't like `javascript` behaviour and I need to initialise the function first before calling it. And I should drop the `list` class and instead use the `nth` directly. Something like this.

```
$screen:       "(only screen)" !default
$medium-range:  (40.063em, 64em)

@function upper-bound($list)
    @return nth($list, 2)

@function lower-bound($list)
    @return nth($list, 1)

$medium-only:  "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})" !default
```